# Generate JSONH in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

Postgresql has excellent JSON support now. However, I find myself struggling in attempting to package data from tables/views in the JSONH format to reduce payload size.  Wonder anyone could share his/her approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following, still had to concatenate columns and put double-quotes around char-fields.  Hope there are better solutions.

```
WITH c AS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME 
            FROM information_schema.columns t
            WHERE TABLE_NAME='my_table_name'),
    a AS (SELECT col1 || ',"' || col2 || '","' || col3 || '"' 
            FROM my_table_name)
SELECT jsonb_build_array(
    array_to_string(array(SELECT count(1)::text FROM c),',') || ',' ||
    array_to_string (array(SELECT COLUMN_NAME::text FROM c), ',') || ',' ||
    array_to_string(array(SELECT * FROM a), ','));
```